# KNIME - how can be decide seed value on x-partition node in the anime

Tags: seed, knime

I used Artificial Neural Network . So I need to seed value but I do not what value will I set ?

Comment: Anything. That is required only for reproducibilty, but it should work for any value.

Comment: when I change seed value, the accuracy percentage value changed

Comment: That is expected, though ideally for most of the seed values it should be similar/close to other seed arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever number you want as seed. It is used for the initilization and shouldn't make a big difference. Setting a seed is useful if you want to have reproducable code/workflow and is mostly used for testing purposes.